# Can we construct a continuous but nowhere differentiable surface?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, differential-topology, examples-counterexamples

In my analysis course we learned about the Weierstrass function which is continuous but nowhere differentiable, is it possible to make a surface which is continuous and nowhere differentiable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $W$ is Weierstrass function, let $z=W(x)\,W(y)$.